# Leaflet: update map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Here is my function that I use to draw a Leaflet map in my website:

```
function drawTweetMap(points) {
    if (tweetMap != null)
        tweetMap.remove();  

    var london = [51.505, -0.09];
    tweetMap = L.map('tweetMap').setView(london, 5);

    var cloudmadeUrl = 'http://{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg';
    var subDomains = ['otile1','otile2','otile3','otile4'];
    var cloudmadeAttrib = 'Data, imagery and map information provided by <a href="http://open.mapquest.co.uk" target="_blank">MapQuest</a>, <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap</a> and contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/" target="_blank">CC-BY-SA</a>';
    L.tileLayer(cloudmadeUrl, 
                  {attribution: cloudmadeAttrib, 
                   maxZoom: 18,
                   subdomains: subDomains})
    .addTo(tweetMap);

    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
    var points_rand = L.geoJson(points, {onEachFeature: onEachFeature});
    markers.addLayer(points_rand);
    tweetMap.addLayer(markers);
    tweetMap.fitBounds(markers.getBounds());
}
```

This function is called periodically:

```
mapWatch = setInterval(function() {
    retrieveCurrentTweetPositions()},
numMinutes*60*1000);
```

in this function:

```
function retrieveCurrentTweetPositions() {
    var points = retrieveCurrentPositions();
    var mapInput = translatePointsInMapFormat(points);
    drawTweetMap(mapInput);
}
```

Unfortunately, if the map is drawn in this way, the result is the following: 
[image]

In other questions I found that it is possible to invalidate the size of the map to fix this problem, so it was suggested to call on startup this function:

```
function updateTweetMapPosition() { 
    setTimeout(function(){
        tweetMap.invalidateSize(true);}
    ,500)
}
```

I did so, and this solves the problem during the first map drawing. However, when I try to redraw the map for a second time, the result is as follows:

[image]

Has anyone experienced this problem? How can I redraw the map with a full loading of its content?

Thanks.

---

**EDIT**

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qzpwvqzk/

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem as follows

setTimeout(function(){map.invalidateSize(true);},500);

Answer (score 1):

Use https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-invalidatesize

```
tweetMap.invalidateSize()
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`redraw()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-redraw) method.

Comment: Where did you call `tweetMap.redraw();`?

Comment: I tried by substituting the first two lines with  `if (tweetMap != null) {tweetMap.eachLayer(function (layer) {layer.redraw();}); }` but it says that the method is undefined

Comment: `redraw()` needs to be called on `tweetMap`.

Comment: It happens the same thing. It says that it is undefined: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'tweetMap.redraw()')`

Comment: And where are you calling that? A jsFiddle with your complete code would be super helpful :)

Comment: That's not a working jsFiddle. I've cleaned it up a bit but there are still some functions missing. http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/hc3v8mjy/

Comment: `retrieveCurrentPositions()` is the only one missing because it goes for a REST call to my server. What else is missing?

Comment: And `toggle()`, and `activate()`.

Comment: The goal is to get the code working on jsFiddle so we can debug and get it working.